# Assigning a domain name in my local network (RaspAP on RPI4)

Tags: wifi, access-point

For my final presentation this semester, I have setup a local network using RaspAP on my RPI 4+. I have a websever available locally @ 10.3.141.91 and I would like to assign it a domain name (example.com) so I don't have to type the IP adress. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Make an entry in /etc/hosts setup DNS? The same way you would do this on any other Linux machine.

Comment: Welcome -- you might want to clarify that it is on the Pi that you want to do this, ie., the "local server" is on some other machine that will connect to the Pi AP, and then the Pi will attempt to connect to the webserver on that other machine.  If this is *not* how it is, then explain the details.

Comment: hello, yes some clarification. The local server is hosted on the RPI. Hopefully clients will connect to the RPI wifi AP and access the webserver not by typing a local IP address (10.3.141.90 but example.com)

Comment: RpiOS by default runs an [avahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)) daemon, which implements mDNS.  Most personal computers and smartphones also make use of this.  Note that Steve's first comment is inapplicable due to your clarification.  You should edit it into the question as it still reads like my previous comment.

Comment: Have you installed `dnsmasq` on your RPi? If not, how are you providing DNS resolution on your local network? Is your RaspAP part of a local network - or is it on a different network? If you're going to ask network questions, your question must provide some details. Otherwise, your only answer will be to read the [*"Milliways Network Tutorial"*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697).

Answer (score 0):

You can connect from most computers on your local network with *hostname*.local (for most this is `raspberrypi.local`)

See *Connecting a Computer to the Pi* in
[How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)